# Converge definition to justify convergence of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Find $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} S_n$. Justify using definition of convergence/divergence of  a sequence: $$S_n =2 + \frac{1}{n+1}$$

The limit:
$$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} S_n = \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} 2 + \frac{1}{n+1} = 2$$

Since $$|S_n -2| = |2 + \frac{1}{n+1} -2|= \frac{1}{1+n} < \epsilon$$

Hence if $\epsilon>0$, then $S_n$ holds with $s=2$ if $N\geq \frac{1}{\epsilon}$

---

The question I have regards the process to find the last part that I believe (hopefully) is correct: $N\geq \frac{1}{\epsilon}$

Given
$$\frac{1}{1+n} < \epsilon$$
solving for n
$$n > 1/\epsilon - 1 $$
Given that $n \geq N$
$$n > 1/\epsilon - 1  \geq N $$

.

What is the process to find $N\geq \frac{1}{\epsilon}$ ?

thx for the help.

Comment: How did you get that $\frac{1}{\varepsilon - 1} \geq N$? It's not always true that $a>b \land a \geq c \implies b \geq c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $N \geq \frac{1}{\varepsilon}$. Then we want to show that for any $n \geq N$, it is true that $|S_n - 2| \leq \varepsilon$. Indeed,
$$|S_n - 2| = \left|2+\frac{1}{n+1} - 2\right| = \left|\frac{1}{n+1}\right|$$
But $n \geq N$, so $n+1 > N$ and $\frac{1}{n+1} < \frac{1}{N} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{\varepsilon}} = \varepsilon$, as desired.